# Recent posts with comment count in "Sidebar" template

Tags: theme-development, comments, recent-posts

I tried this code, but it totally broke my site. I suppose it's because I'm doing something wrong in the WP_Query's sacred posts context in the sidebar template. Could some WP guru please correct this code?

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date'
    ,'order' => 'DESC'
    ,'showposts'=>6
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

  echo "<dl>";

  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

  $recent_title = get_the_title();
  $recent_link  = get_the_permalink();
  $recent_date  = get_the_date();
  $recent_count = $post->comment_count;
  if ($recent_count < 1)        { $recent_count = 'Leave a Comment&nbsp;'; }
  else                          { $recent_count = "$recent_count <span class='iv'>Comments&nbsp;</span>"; }


  echo "<dt>$recent_date &nbsp; / &nbsp; <span class='comment'><a href='$recent_link#disqus_thread'>$recent_count</a></span></dt><dd><a href='$recent_link' title='$recent_title'>$recent_title</a></dd>"

  echo "</dl>";

  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().

?>
```

Just in case this doesn't appear properly formatted, here's the code on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d55ceb482732b98c4bc3)

I really do NOT want to use a plugin for this simple functionality.

Comment: This is not *WP_Query's sacred posts context*, but plain pure php. The same syntax for php goes for Wordpress. Get yourself a proper syntax highlighter, this will help you in future

Comment: Add the missing semicolon.

Comment: I'm not sure this is off topic. If the semicolon was the only missing piece, which makes it a non-Wordpress issue, then sure. Please delete this thread. The community here is awesome, I got the help I needed. (And I already use Coda2, sometimes color coding is not the only thing needed.) Thanks. Btw, further down in the thread there is indeed a helpful variation to the code in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**';'** is missing in this line `echo "<dt>$recent_date &nbsp; / &nbsp; <span class='comment'><a href='$recent_link#disqus_thread'>$recent_count</a></span></dt><dd><a href='$recent_link' title='$recent_title'>$recent_title</a></dd>"`

For this reason code is throwing the fatal error. Please replace that line with this code

```
echo "<dt>$recent_date &nbsp; / &nbsp; <span class='comment'><a href='$recent_link#disqus_thread'>$recent_count</a></span></dt><dd><a href='$recent_link' title='$recent_title'>$recent_title</a></dd>";
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it! :) Also, what could I add in my code to make sure the current post is excluded from this listing of *other* recent posts? Thanks!

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Answer (score 0):

I did not test the code. But you can try this code.

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date'
    ,'order' => 'DESC'
    ,'showposts'=>6
);

if( is_singular('post')){
  global $post;
  $args['post__not_in'] = array( $post->ID); // Excluding the current post at post details page
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help you.